# TODO markers disappeared in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, todo

I used to see markers on the left column(not sure about the name, it is the area where the debug breakpoints are marked with red dots) for the lines containing *// TODO*.

Somehow this has disappeared. How can I get this feature back?

Edit: I am referring to the green + on the left column.
Here is a screenshot from my older computer that has VS2019 too:
[image]

Comment: how did those markers looked like? I think, by default, there only a list of TODOs in the Task list window.

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik: I am not referring to the task list. The markers were on the left hand column of the editor pane

Comment: I'm asking how did they looked like as there's nothing like that by default in VS2019 - so you must have had some add-on installed that added those.